# WPF binding in design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am tring to bind some properties in design-time. Note that everything works 
just fine in runtime.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.TestControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:TestViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding FontSize}" Text="Test!" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public int FontSize
    {
        get { return 40; }
    }
}
```

To make it work in the real app, i added to the constructor of the XAML:

```
DataContext = new TestViewModel();
```

Every thing works just fine in runtime, but not in design time.

Expected Result: Text block with font size of 40px
Result in the designer: Text block with font size of 12px

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Change the FontSize property to return a double. Your code works fine here, both runtime and design time.

Comment: Oops, typing mistake. The property returning int, but it still not working...

Comment: A couple of people are saying that it works fine for them, so it must be something else within your solution.  Perhaps the namespace BindingTest is not correct for you?

Comment: This is very wired. I will test it again.